# Reducing light dimming when AC units urn on

Tags: dimming, brownout

Currently I use two 60 W incandescent bulbs and and a standard rotation dimmer in the office.  When the A/Cs turn on on the 2nd floor these lights dim significantly and sometimes turn off. All wiring is relatively new.

Are there LED lights and/or dimmers that will "buffer" the momentary drop? They come back to normal lighting after about 1 s.

Comment: Unlikely that there is such a lamp/dimmer, but you can probably solve your problem by adding a UPS in series with your lights. This will add some permanent power consumption (inefficiency) to your system.

Comment: No buffering. Unless you change the bulbs to LED with some range (wide would be ideal) and dim them in some other fashion, you will have this effect. There are voltage regulators for AC mains and a UPS as Wesley suggests would negate this too. A bit overkill though.

Comment: That appears as a problem with the main electrical system. You are not getting enough current from the electrical supply company to the building. It could be undersized transformer, bad connections, or the supply company is overloaded and cannot supply more power. You will need a professional to determine the exact cause. First I would contact the power company and complain to them. You can also run a small tungsten lamp without a dimmer and see if it also dims, if so that would confirm the power problem.

Comment: Even a UPS won't be fast enough -- your eye will notice a drop in intensity with a dropout of just ½ a mains cycle, and UPS don't generally kick in until at least a full cycle has been missed (because their loads DO have buffers (capacitors). Some LED bulb may have sufficient internal filtering capacitance, but this also will only hold up over ½ a cycle.

Comment: Check the starting capacitor  to the compressor motor to you air conditioner.

Comment: I agree, get an electrician's opinion on this. I know lights can dim slightly and that's not abnormal, but you mention they dim so far they turn off, which **is** abnormal and could be caused by faulty wiring. You say it's relatively new, doesn't that mean it could've been done wrong?

Comment: You can get LED's bulbs with internal supplies  that work on 100 to 240V power.  They won't significantly dim until the voltage drops below 100V.  That may not be enough for 120VAC power, but is significant for 240VAC power.

Comment: There are too many unknowns to answer this question well.  Apparently the lights and the air conditioner are on the same step-down transformer.  We don't know if the transformer is too small (not able to supply the current) or if the power grid to the transformer  is in brown out from overload, so that the voltage to the transformer is too low.  One of these seems most likely since  breakers aren't blowing on a hot day.